# Viewing opentelemetry traces in Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, azure-monitor

I'm sending opentelemetry traces to Azure Monitor (via Application Insights) following [this guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter_1.0.0-beta.3/sdk/monitor/Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter/README.md).

Does Application Insights have a view similar to something like what Jaeger, Zipkin and Tempo offer, or can I only view the traces as log entries in a table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes Application Insights has a very rich UI you can go to and view application map, failures, performance + it gives you a full view of all the logs via KQL.

For a waterfall like UI you have multiple places this is shown.
You can go to Requests, check a sample request and clicking on it will give you a waterfall view.

Although in my example, it's just a sample and I don't have many dependencies ie: if there was a downstream db call, api call etc it will show a clear waterfall with time slices etc

Or if you have a transactionId/Correlation ID then you can enter it in the "Transaction Search" and it will lead to a similar waterfall like UI

[image]

[image]

[Here is a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paAYgjNITik) which shows all the major views in application insights

Comment: But is there a “waterfall” like UI as the ones Jaeger, Zipkin, etc offer? Where you can search for and see a single trace and the duration of all the individual spans. Haven’t found one 

Comment: Yes, it is called "End-to-end transaction diagnostics". For instance, you can open "Transaction search", paste transaction id (operation id in Application Insights terminology; or any other field), click on individual telemetry item and it will open "end-to-end" with the whole trace.

Comment: @ZakiMa Thanks! Leaves a bit to wish for but definitely what I was looking for!  Please write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Right I see, so if its just the "waterfall" like UI then the like for like is the transaction search like @ZakiMa mentioned or via the Requests menu option.

Comment: @Joel, if you have feedback about End-to-end (or Application Insights in general), feel free to open a separate Stack Overflow question or send me to my SO alias at microsoft.